# Symfony 2 use the wrong mysql installation on mac/mamp

Tags: mysql, macos, symfony

I use `3306` port for mysql in MAMP PRO (mac) with this Symfony 2 configuration:

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     127.0.0.1
    database_port:     3306
    database_name:     modcanyon
    database_user:     root
    database_password: root
```

When I use `doctrine:database:create`, I have this error :

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

If I change the password for use the password of my local (mac, not mamp) mysql installation, the command line run without problem, but the database is created on the local mysql installation and not on MAMP.

Why Symfony 2 don't use the MAMP mysql installation ?

Comment: What is the purpose of using multiple mysql installations?

Comment: What is the IP of your MAMP ? If this is 127.0.0.1 too, what is the port of your Mysql Service on the MAMP server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line bellow in parameters.yml fix the problem:
`database_path: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Example:

```
parameters:
    database_driver:   pdo_mysql
    database_host:     localhost
    database_port:     3306
    database_name:     modcanyon
    database_user:     root
    database_password: root
    database_path: /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Visit http://localhost/MAMP/ for find more informations about your mysql server (socket, login, ip, etc.)